# Popular question badge seems not optimal

Tags: discussion, badges, popular-question

This question of mine has been awarded the popular question badge presumably only because it's title was inadvertently overly broad. Isn't there a way to undo that? doesn't this badge fall prone to this problem on a large proportion of its occurrences?

[HBase fails to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533283/hbase-fails-to-start)

Comment: Weird. Many people would do anything to get badges and you're asking to undo your received badge.

Comment: It's been around for over 1 year, I wouldn't say that it's a problem that it's finally had 1,000 views.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to undo that (unless Stack Exchange Devs can jump in and do their magic). Normally, when a badge gets awarded it is not revoked so don't worry about it.

However, you may edit the question title appropriately so it doesn't get the next in line "Notable Question" and "Famous Question" badges :)